# Rendered videos have no sound

Tags: 14.10, video-editor

Since I upgraded to 14.10 I can't render videos with sound. It happens both in Openshot and Kdenlive, and in more than one codec.
I saw this answer: [No audio in rendered video files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541635/no-audio-in-rendered-video-files), but it was no good for me. I already had both packages installed and in the same folder, so that's not it.
Tracks are unmuted, audio works fine everywhere else, including the video-editors themselves. It's just after the render that the audio is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is the same as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/548279/4733), to a different question.

You need newer versions of [libmlt6](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mlt) and [libmlt++3](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mlt) than what Ubuntu 14.10 shipped.  15.04 already has the newer packages.

You can work around the problem on your 14.10 system by simply grabbing the newer version from 15.04 and installing them:

```
cd $(mktemp -d)
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libmlt%2B%2B3_0.9.2%2Bgit20141027-1_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libmlt6_0.9.2%2Bgit20141027-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -Oi *deb
```

Answer (score 0):

VERY bad advice, to install libs from a different release. The package is simply busted, no argument about it.

In any case, you might break the packages that depend on it, which are:

```
Reverse Depends: kdenlive (>= 0.9.8-1ubuntu2)
Reverse Depends: libmlt++3 (>= 0.9.2-1build1)
Reverse Depends: libmlt-dbg (= 0.9.2-1build1)
Reverse Depends: libmlt-dev (= 0.9.2-1build1)
Reverse Depends: melt (>= 0.9.2-1build1)
Reverse Depends: python-mlt (>= 0.9.2-1build1)
kdenlive
Reverse Depends: kdenlive-dbg (= 0.9.8-1ubuntu2)
kdenlive-dbg
libmlt++3
Reverse Depends: kdenlive (>= 0.9.8-1ubuntu2)
Reverse Depends: libmlt++-dev (= 0.9.2-1build1)
Reverse Depends: libmlt-dbg (= 0.9.2-1build1)
Reverse Depends: python-mlt (>= 0.9.2-1build1)
libmlt++-dev
libmlt-dbg
python-mlt
Reverse Depends: flowblade (0.8.0-3)
Reverse Depends: openshot (1.4.3-1.1)
flowblade
openshot
libmlt-dev
melt
Reverse Depends: kdenlive (0.9.8-1ubuntu2)
Reverse Depends: openshot (1.4.3-1.1)
```

libmlt++3:
    libmlt++3
      Reverse Depends: kdenlive (>= 0.9.8-1ubuntu2)
      Reverse Depends: libmlt++-dev (= 0.9.2-1build1)
      Reverse Depends: libmlt-dbg (= 0.9.2-1build1)
      Reverse Depends: python-mlt (>= 0.9.2-1build1)
    kdenlive
      Reverse Depends: kdenlive-dbg (= 0.9.8-1ubuntu2)
    kdenlive-dbg
    libmlt++-dev
    libmlt-dbg
    python-mlt
      Reverse Depends: flowblade (0.8.0-3)
      Reverse Depends: openshot (1.4.3-1.1)
    flowblade
    openshot

Answer (score 0):

I just started learning Linux, so I don't know a lot of stuff yet. Anyway here is my update. Dustin Kirkland's advice may have worked (kind of), but there's more that I did than the commands in the terminal.

1. I tried doing the following after entering the commands suggested by Dustin, and I think the stuff in this step may have worked without doing the updates he suggested. Separate the audio into an mp3 using VLC player, then put it into the audio slot in the session with the video that you are editing in Kdenlive and mute the video in the video slot. Then render the video. If that doesn't work then do the following steps and repeat this one. I think this would have worked in my case because there was one second of sound in the edited videos before I used the mp3.
2. Enter what Dustin said to enter into the command prompt. It may say the same stuff on your screen as it did for me (all that stuff after @ Terminal output section of this comment).
3. After that, open the Ubuntu Software Center. I was prompted by it to finish installing stuff (I don't remember what it said). I clicked *OK*.
4. For some reason Kdenlive was no longer installed, so I reinstalled it.

Terminal output after entering commands that Dustin instructs us to:

```
(Reading database ... 213948 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libmlt++3_0.9.2+git20141027-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmlt++3 (0.9.2+git20141027-1) over (0.9.0-3) ...
Preparing to unpack libmlt6_0.9.2+git20141027-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmlt6 (0.9.2+git20141027-1) over (0.9.0-3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmlt6:
 libmlt6 depends on libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) | libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11); however:
  Package libavcodec56 is not installed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-56 is not installed.
 libmlt6 depends on libavdevice55 (>= 6:11~beta1); however:
  Package libavdevice55 is not installed.
 libmlt6 depends on libavformat56 (>= 6:11~beta1); however:
  Package libavformat56 is not installed.
 libmlt6 depends on libavutil54 (>= 6:11~beta1); however:
  Package libavutil54 is not installed.
 libmlt6 depends on libswscale3 (>= 6:11~beta1); however:
  Package libswscale3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libmlt6 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmlt++3:
 libmlt++3 depends on libmlt6 (>= 0.9.2+git20141027); however:
  Package libmlt6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmlt++3 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmlt6
 libmlt++3
```